# ECV class breaking vertical line when using portrait

Tags: longtable, europecv, ecv

I've been using the ECV class (for writing CVs) for for a long time and never had any issues with it, however upon updating my CV yesterday I noticed that the vertical line which is drawn through the document (using a longtable I found in the .cls file) breaks at the top (see attached image). Upon commenting out a portrait, it seems fine. I've tried looking at the .cls file without much luck. Anyone who has an idea what might be going on and how to fix the issue?

To clarify, commenting out `\ecvPortrait` seems to fix it, but of course loses the portrait.

Thanks guys!

```
%%
%% Copyright 2006-2011 Christoph P. Neumann, Bernd Haberstumpf
%%
%% This LaTeX file provides a template for a german CV.
%%
%% This file is free property; as a special exception the author
%% gives unlimited permission to copy and/or distribute it, with
%% or without modifications, as long as this notice is
%% preserved.
%%
%% This file is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
%% but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law;
%% without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
%% FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
%%

\documentclass[english]{ecv}

% Dateiname: images/<portrait>.jpg
\ecvPortrait{portrait.jpg}
\ecvName{Last name, First name}



\begin{document}
```

[image: vertical line next to Curriculum Vitae breaking when having a portrait in the document (personal information sensored)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I identified and fixed the problem. The new version 0.4.0 (not yet on CTAN) can be found in my GitHub repository https://github.com/poldi2015/ecv. The class file `ecv.cls` need to be replaced.

Comment: Bernd, could you expand your answer to include an explanation as to what exactly was the problem? That might help people dealing with broken vertical lines in other contexts...